# Specify shown labels for date x axis ggplot2

Tags: r, date, ggplot2

I have the following example dataframe and code:

```
library(ggplot2)

data <- data.frame(date=as.Date(c("05.08.2021","07.08.2021","09.08.2021","27.08.2021","02.09.2021"), format = "%d.%m.%Y"),event=as.numeric(c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")))
    
ggplot(data=data, aes(x=date, y=event, group=1))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_point()
```

The outputted plot shows random dates on the x axis. I want R to show only five given dates on the x axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `scale_x_date`:

```r
ggplot(data=data, aes(x = date, y=event, group=1))+
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_date(breaks = data$date, labels = format(data$date, "%b %d"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for ur help! Can you tell me how to define manual date x labels like that for facet grid plots?

Comment: You can open a different question if you think the answer will be different. If you have the same breaks, this answer should be working.